# Discord FFmpeg не найден

Tags: python, discord.py, ffmpeg

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Бот подключен как {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_channel = await channel.connect()


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    # Проигрывание аудиофайла
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file("hello.mp3", format="mp3")
    play(audio)

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()


bot.run('токен')
```

Ошибка - discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

Название mp3 файла указано верно, много раз проверил

Еще в начале предупреждение - C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)